# Wave packets Group Velocity

Tags: waves

For the the [group velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) of a wave packet, the group velocity is the partial derivative of omega with respect to the wavenumber, what does this mean? I thought that for some given wave packet both the angular frequency and wave number should be fixed, so what differentiation $d$ is there?

Comment: What is the formula where this $d$ appears in it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity#Derivation

Comment: It say "where ω is implicitly a function of k", so you can take derivatives. Also, it's important to ask, how would you define angular frequency $\omega$ for a wave packet??

Comment: I know, that was what I was trying to ask. Why would angular frequency be a function of k, if k is constant?

Comment: You cannot make a wave *packet* with a single wavelength/frequency! You need a spread of wavelength and frequency components in order to localise the wavepacket in space (this is the mathematical basis of the uncertainty principle). If it does not make sense that the frequency of a plane wave does depend on the wavelength you ought to review the wave equation.

Answer (score 10):

Supposedly if you have a wave packet you don't have a "single frequency" or "single wavelength". In order for you to have a wave-packet you have a superposition of waves of different frequencies and wave-lengths.

Imagine you superpose two sinusoidal progressive waves which have different frequencies and wavelengths in a dispersive medium (there will be wave dispersion). The waves have the same amplitude (just to make it easier).
Let's define the waves this way:

$$ y_{1}=Acos(k_{1}x-\omega_{1}t) $$
$$ y_{2}=Acos(k_{2}x-\omega_{2}t) $$

As they are in a dispersive medium their velocity might be different:
$$\frac{\omega_{1}}{k_{1}}= v_{1}$$ $$ \frac{\omega_{2}}{k_{2}}=v_{2}$$
If we write $$ \psi(x,t)=y_{1}+y_{2}$$
we can get:
$$ \psi(x,t)=Acos(k_{1}x-\omega_{1}t)+Acos(k_{2}x-\omega_{2}t)$$ $$=2Acos(\frac{k_{1}-k_{2}}{2}x+\frac{\omega_{2}-\omega_{1}}{2}t)cos(\frac{k_{1}+k_{2}}{2}x-\frac{\omega_{2}+\omega_{1}}{2}t) $$
That last one came from this trigonometric identity: $$cos(a)+cos(b)=2cos(\frac{a+b}{2})cos(\frac{a-b}{2})$$

If we write $$ \omega_{0}= \frac{\omega_{2}+\omega_{1}}{2};\Delta \omega=\frac{\omega_{2}-\omega_{1}}{2};k_{0}= \frac{k_{2}+k_{1}}{2};\Delta k=\frac{k_{2}-k_{1}}{2}$$
The expression before will be simplified:
$$ \psi(x,t)= 2Acos(\Delta k\cdot x+\Delta \omega \cdot t)cos(k_{0}x-\omega_{0}t)$$

You will know the phase velocity when you compute $v_p=\omega_0/k_0$ and you will get the group velocity when you compute $v_{g}=\Delta \omega/\Delta k$.

The idea that the group velocity is the partial derivative of omega in respect to the wavenumber comes from the idea that the initial frequencies $\omega_{1}$ and $\omega_{2}$ are very close values (and so is the wave number). Then you will have beats:

$v_{g}=lim(\Delta \omega /\Delta k)=lim(\frac{\omega_{2}(k_{2})-\omega_{1}(k_{1})}{k_{2}-k_{1}}) $ where $\omega_{1}≈\omega_{2}$, leading to:
$$v_{g}=\frac{∂w}{∂k}$$

And there you have it. To conclude, in a wave-packet you don't have a single frequency or wavenumber, but several. This brings the necessity to compute the phase velocity (which is the velocity at which the waves inside the wave-packet envelope travel) and the group velocity (the velocity of the envelope that contains the waves). I'm sorry for any bad english.
Hope I helped. Happy new year.

Comment: amazing answer , so to "cosntruct" a wave packet we should pick waves with really close values of $\omega$ and k?

Comment: @brucebanner The closer the frequencies are, the longer the wave packet keeps its shape. The further apart those frequencies and wave numbers are, the faster the shape of the wave packet is distorted and eventually disappears. Hope this helped